# How does Node set its environment variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When running a Node application, how does Node know what environment it is running in?

I understand that the environment is defined within `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but how and where is that variable defined?

Comment: it can be defined at user profile file or you can set it before starting node

Comment: It depends how Environment variables are defined and assigned. If it is stored in `.bashrc` file, it is alway there, if it is set just before starting a node program, it remains in memory unless machine is restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There multiple ways of setting node variables but most common

**1. is to start your console with them enabled** as following:

```
> NODE_ENV=prod node start.js
process.env.NODE_ENV // prod
```

But there are times when you can explicitly set the env before the start of the file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
require('config') // then it will return me the test.json config

// I use this technique mostly for unit tests
```

---

**2. export the envars in the `package.json`**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=dev && node server.js", // for linux
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node server", // for windows
    "test": "mocha"
  },
```

When you run `npm start` the script will run the server in `dev` mode

---

**3. use a npm package as `dotenv` and setup a `.env` file**

Plugins for env management as [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) the most common used one. Where you can create `.env` files with needed ENV variables

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Comment: When code is running in an environment like Heroku, does the Heroku server then explicitly set the environment variable to "production"?

Comment: In your dyno `Settings > Config variables` it is after `application name`, you can expand this tab and then add and edit all `env` variables that you need.
All the variables there will be accessible through `process.env`

Answer (score 0):

These usually are set in `package.json` commands or come from a `.env` file.

For example, `NODE_ENV=development` from a `.env` file can be accessed in `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

For loading `.env` files into `process.env` check out [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Answer (score 0):

The variable isn't defined unless you define it.
I guess you are using a regular Windows machine.
On Windows you can simply do this.
create a random index file and put this in it: `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`
and then run it with: `set NODE_ENV=productionEnvironment && node index`